# In the beautiful language of hebrew what is Todah?

Tags: words, hebrew

***I went to a synagogue the other day and after presenting the chief rabbi with an apple he exclaimed 'TODAH!'.
Anyone know what this means?***

Comment: Hi and welcome to Mi Yodeya.  Questions about the Hebrew language (except in contexts like prayer, torah text, etc) are off-topic here, but see Josh's answer for some helpful information.  You may be interested in our other questions about [tag:hebrew].  I hope you enjoy the site.

Comment: Also, please support [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36772/hebrew-language?referrer=0VxOXYSlEvp6JgswQkbPfw2) for a StackExchange site about the Hebrew language.

Answer (score 5):

It means thank you.
Here is a transliterated hebrew dictionary of sorts, such that you can write a word by typing English letters and get a translation.
http://www.doitinhebrew.com/Translate/default.aspx?kb=IL+Hebrew+Phonetic#.UtkkCH-9KSM